# How to Center Titles in Forest Trees?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

Here goes my third question. I am actually drawing Game Theory trees using the package Forest, and I have a small issue with the title of some Trees that I cannot manage. Essentially, I order LaTex to put the titles centered, but its behavior is to center them at the top node of the tree. This is fine when the tree is symmetric or almost symmetric, but looks rather strange when the tree is not. Then, I was wondering if there is any way to center the title such that it is in the centre of the entire tree and not centered in the top node. In sum, this is the tree I currently have, and I would like to slightly move the title to the right (if possible).
[image]

The code I am using is this one:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{forest} for tree={l sep=4em, s sep=8em, anchor=center}
[$P_1$, circle, draw,
    [{2, 2}, edge label={node[midway,left]{$D$}}]
    [$P_2$, edge label={node[midway,right]{$A$}}, circle, draw, 
        [{1, 1}, edge label={node[midway,left]{$d$}}] 
        [$P_1$, edge label={node[midway,right]{$a$}}, circle, draw,
            [{0, 0}, edge label={node[midway,left]{$D$}}]
            [{3, 3}, edge label={node[midway,right]{$A$}}]]]]
\node[above=30pt,align=center,anchor=center] {\textbf{Figure IV.} Extensive Form of a Centipede Game Variant};
\end{forest}
\end{center}
```

PS: If anyone knows how to slightly separate the letters that designate actions (D,A,d,a,D,A) to avoid that they overlap with the branches of the tree, it will be just awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're setting the caption as a node, which is also not the standard way of doing this. Captions are added to figures in a Latex document *externally* to the picture, i.e. they are not part of it.

Also, you're manually assigning a number to your figure and this makes the use of Latex a bit pointless, because one of the great advantages of using Latex is that captions are automatically numbered.

You can customize them, but they are automatic, so if you add another figure, they are all automatically fixed, while in your case, you'd have to fix each one manually. And that is not good in a long document.

You can add `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}` to your preamble to make figure numbering with uppercase Roman numerals, and `\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}` to make it bold.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}

\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Extensive Form of a Centipede Game Variant}
\medskip
\begin{forest} for tree={l sep=4em, s sep=8em, anchor=center}
[$P_1$, circle, draw,
    [{2, 2}, edge label={node[midway,left]{$D$}}]
    [$P_2$, edge label={node[midway,right]{$A$}}, circle, draw, 
        [{1, 1}, edge label={node[midway,left]{$d$}}] 
        [$P_1$, edge label={node[midway,right]{$a$}}, circle, draw,
            [{0, 0}, edge label={node[midway,left]{$D$}}]
            [{3, 3}, edge label={node[midway,right]{$A$}}]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Man, you are a Master. My life is much easier now. Thank you very much. By the way, I have taken a look at the link you suggested in the other question I have, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I get close to it, but not enough.

Comment: @Héctor Ahah thanks, this is not hard stuff so I doubt that makes me a Master. :D But thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Alenanno](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292199/) is entirely correct about how to handle `figure` captions. However, it might nonetheless be useful to know how to centre a node relative to the tree.

This can be done by centring the node relative to the current bounding box of the picture, after the entire tree is drawn, rather than centring it relative to some particular node.

```
    \node at ([yshift=10pt]current bounding box.north) {Centred within Tree: Extensive Form of a Centipede Game Variant};
```

[Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292209/) is quite correct, as well, but I'm lazier and prefer to handle things automatically. So I'd use something which made specifying the tree, including the labels, a bit simpler by modifying the tree's preamble a bit.

```
  \begin{forest}
```

First, let's create a style with the options common to all `edge label`s. This will be some positive `inner sep` and `midway`.

```
    /tikz/my edge label/.style={inner sep=5pt, midway},
```

Now for the tree configuration.

```
    for tree={
      l sep=4em,
      s sep=8em,
      anchor=center,
```

We'll delay our changes a bit to make sure the options are set.

```
      before typesetting nodes={
```

If the node is the first child going from right to left, then any edge labels should be set on the right, as well as using the style for all edge labels. Also, the `edge label` specification is essentially the same in all cases, so we might as well do the whole `node ...` thing here as well.

```
        if n'=1{
          edge label/.wrap value={\noexpand node [my edge label,right] {$#1$} }
```

If not, the node must be on the left, because all parent nodes have exactly zero or two children. (Either `n=1` or `n'=1` except for the root node which couldn't have an `edge label` being nobody's child at all.)

```
        }{
          edge label/.wrap value={\noexpand node [my edge label,left] {$#1$} }
        },
      },
```

All non-terminal nodes get the options `circle` and `draw`, so we don't need to specify the options manually each time.

```
      if n children=0{}{
        circle,
        draw,
      }
    }
```

With this configuration in place, we can specify the tree in the following way.

```
    [$P_1$
      [{2, 2}, edge label=D]
      [$P_2$, edge label=A
        [{1, 1}, edge label=d]
        [$P_1$, edge label=a
          [{0, 0}, edge label=D]
          [{3, 3}, edge label=A]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

to produce

[image: lazier tree specification]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Extensive Form of a Centipede Game Variant}
  \medskip
  \begin{forest}
    /tikz/my edge label/.style={inner sep=5pt, midway},
    for tree={
      l sep=4em,
      s sep=8em,
      anchor=center,
      before typesetting nodes={
        if n'=1{
          edge label/.wrap value={\noexpand node [my edge label,right] {$#1$} }
        }{
          edge label/.wrap value={\noexpand node [my edge label,left] {$#1$} }
        },
      },
      if n children=0{}{
        circle,
        draw,
      }
    }
    [$P_1$
      [{2, 2}, edge label=D]
      [$P_2$, edge label=A
        [{1, 1}, edge label=d]
        [$P_1$, edge label=a
          [{0, 0}, edge label=D]
          [{3, 3}, edge label=A]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    \node at ([yshift=10pt]current bounding box.north) {Centred within Tree: Extensive Form of a Centipede Game Variant};
  \end{forest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I have used the solutions already posted by the other users, but the code your provide is somehow simpler and quite nice. Thank you very much!

Comment: @cfr  I need to go through a complete tutorial on creating styles for `tikzset` and `forest`  starting from basic to advanced  -- request your help in this

Answer (score 2):

Regarding  distance between edge labels and edges, see if the following addition to Alenanno's code gives what you looking for:

```
\tikzset{el/.style = {% edge label
    midway, outer sep=1.5mm, #1} % <--- #1: for position (left, right)
        }
```

Put this before `\begin{forest}` and than instead of `edge label={node[midway,left]{...}` use

```
edge label={node[el=left]{...}
```

or

```
edge label={node[el=right]{...}
```

depending on which side of the edge the label should go. With it the graph becomes:

[image]

Comment: Yeah! That works great!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Another example of using the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package. You can simply use the abbreviations `[al]` or `[ar]` to get some distance between action labels and branches.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{istgame}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Extensive Form of a Centipede Game Variant}
\bigskip
\begin{istgame}
\setistEllipseNodeStyle{7mm}
\setistmathTF111
\xtdistance{6em}{10em}
\istrooto(0){P_1}
  \istb{D}[al]{2,2} \istb{A}[ar] \endist
\istrooto(1)(0-2){P_2}
  \istb{d}[al]{1,1} \istb{a}[ar] \endist
\istrooto(2)(1-2){P_1}
  \istb{D}[al]{0,0} \istb{A}[ar]{3,3} \endist
\end{istgame}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```