# Tikz: Adding Labels to Arrows (Code Given)

Tags: tikz-pgf

the following code produces a decision tree that looks like this:

[image]
and I'm trying to give labels to some of the arrows, like the 'x' you see in the bottom left arrow. For some reason, I can't seem to replicate it on the other arrows?

```
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily}
}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,level/.style={sibling distance = 7cm/#1,
  level distance = 2cm}] 
\node [] {Bruises}
    child{ node [] {Gill size} 
            child{ node [] {Spore Color} 
                child{ node [] {Yes} edge from parent node[above left] {$x$}} %for a named pointer
                            child{ node [] {No}}
            }
            child{ node [] {Habitat}
                child{ node [] {Yes}}
                            child{ node [] {No}}
            }                            
    }
    child{ node [] {Texture of stalk surface below ring}
            child{ node [] {Number of rings} 
                child{ node [] {Yes}} 
                            child{ node [] {No}}
            }
            child{ node [] {Odor}
                child{ node [] {Yes}}
                            child{ node [] {No}}
            }
        }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{An example depth 3 decision tree built on the mush dataset.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I can't seem to be able to replace the 'x' with text`? Changing `$x$` to, say, `abcd`, works fine for me

Comment: Oh, that's strange. I can replace the x now, but I still can't figure out how to put the labels on the other arrows.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid confusion when using `edge from parent node`, I think the best practice is to give your nodes some names. In this way you can literally draw and add paths between any of your nodes with any coordinates.

This is an example.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,level/.style={sibling distance = 7cm/#1,
  level distance = 2cm}] 
\node [] {Bruises}
    child{ node [] {Gill size} 
            child{ node [] {Spore Color} 
                child{ node [] {Yes} edge from parent node[above left] {abcd}} %for a named pointer
                            child{ node [] {No}}
            }
            child{ node [] (c) {Habitat}
                child{ node [] {Yes}}
                            child{ node [] {No}}
            }                            
    }
    child{ node [] {Texture of stalk surface below ring}
            child{ node [] (a) {Number of rings} 
                child{ node [] (b) {Yes}} 
                            child{ node [] {No}}
            }
            child{ node [] {Odor}
                child{ node [] {Yes}}
                            child{ node [] {No}}
            }
        }; 
\path (a) -- (b) node[midway,above,sloped] {xyzt};
\draw[->,red] (a) -- (c) node[midway,above] {mn};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to advertize `forest` for that along with [this nice answer by cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292273/121799). The syntax becomes IMHO much simpler, adding an edge label is as simple as adding `,edge label=x` and you can of course add more arrows if you want to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{forest}
/tikz/my edge label/.style={inner sep=5pt, midway},
for tree={edge={->},
      l sep=4em,
      s sep=3em,
      anchor=center,
      before typesetting nodes={
        if n'=1{
          edge label/.wrap value={\noexpand node [my edge label,right] {$#1$} }
        }{
          edge label/.wrap value={\noexpand node [my edge label,left] {$#1$} }
        },
      }
      }
[Bruises
 [Gill size 
  [Spore Color
   [Yes,edge label=x]
   [No,edge label=y]
  ] 
  [Habitat,alias=habitat
   [Yes] 
   [No]
  ]
 ]  
 [Texture of stalk surface below ring,alias=texture
  [Number of rings
   [Yes]
   [No]
  ] 
  [Odor
   [Yes]
   [No]
  ]
 ]
]  
\draw[red,-latex,dashed] (texture) -- (habitat) node[midway,above,sloped]{$z$};
\end{forest}
\caption{An example depth 3 decision tree built on the mush dataset.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]